# Is it possible to use enum's values as value for object key in type declaration?

Tags: typescript, enums, interface

I have **enum HealthPlanStatus** which was generated by *enum HealthPlanStatus*. In the end I would like to use enum's keys and values to generate not only *status* keys for **type IHealthPlanResponse** but also a *title* value as enum's values.

```
export enum HealthPlanStatus {
    Todo = 'To-Do',
    InProgress = 'Working on it',
}
export type IHealthPlanResponse = {
    [status in keyof typeof HealthPlanStatus]: {
        title: string;
    };
};
```

It gives me strict structure where I have a *status* key as enum's key (**Todo, InProgress**...):

```
type IHealthPlanResponse = {
    readonly Todo: {
        title: string;
    };
    readonly InProgress: {
        title: string;
    };
}
```

Also I would like to have a *title* type as enum's values.
For example:

```
 type IHealthPlanResponse = {
    readonly Todo: {
        title: 'To-Do';
    };
    readonly InProgress: {
        title: 'Working on it';
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
export enum HealthPlanStatus {
    Todo = 'To-Do',
    InProgress = 'Working on it',
}
export type IHealthPlanResponse = {
    readonly [status in keyof typeof HealthPlanStatus]: {
        title: (typeof HealthPlanStatus)[status];
    };
};

let t: IHealthPlanResponse = {} as any
const status = t.InProgress.title   // -> HealthPlanStatus.InProgress
```

If you don't like to see the enum 'key' here and want to have the `string` literal as a type you can change it to this:

```
export type IHealthPlanResponse = {
    readonly [status in keyof typeof HealthPlanStatus]: {
        title: `${(typeof HealthPlanStatus)[status]}`;
    };
};

let t: IHealthPlanResponse = {} as any
const status = t.InProgress.title   // -> 'Working on it'
```

Comment: Hello. Is there any way to get the same structure but using intefraces instead of type?

Answer (score 1):

Amazing approach to use enum in one of type's value.

```js
export enum selectedYearTypeValues {
    'currentYear',
    'All'
}

type Props = {
    selectedYear: keyof typeof selectedYearTypeValues;
    setSelectedYear: (value: keyof typeof selectedYearTypeValues) => void;
}
```